# C++ switch in loop goes to default before running again

Tags: c++, c++11

My first program in C++ is a command line survival game.  I have a switch statement in a while loop, but it always goes through once and runs the default choice before getting the users input.  Here's the relevant code:

```
int menu() {
    while (true) {
        char choice = getChoice();
        switch(choice) {
            case 'p':
            {
                system("clear");
                Arena arena(player, difficulty);
                arena.play();
            }
                break;
            case 'u': 
            {
                system("clear");
                player.save();
                player.init();
            }
                break;
            case 'd': 
            {
                system("clear");
                changeDifficulty();
            }
                break;
            case 'q':
            {
                system("clear");
                return 0;  // return menu(); in main()
            }
            default:
            {
                system("clear");
                cout << nInvalid option! Press a key to choose: p, u, s, or q\n\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

getChoice Function

```
char getChoice() {

    cout << "      Main Menu\n";
    cout << "---------------------\n";
    cout << "p - play game" << endl;
    cout << "u - change user" << endl;
    cout << "d - change difficulty" << endl;
    cout << "q - quit\n" << endl;

    char choice = getchar();
    return choice;
}
```

Everything works fine after it goes through once and runs the code from the default option.  Here's what I get every time the program re-enters this loop:

```
Invalid option! Press a key to choose: p, u, s, or q

      Main Menu
---------------------
p - play game
u - change user
d - change difficulty
q - quit
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: My money is on getChoice() consuming the newline character in error.

Comment: How is your `getChoice` function written?

Comment: @Bathsheba - I don't think anyone is going to take you up on that bet :P

Comment: Better try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Isn't step 1 of debugging `cout << "choice=" << choice << std::endl;` Isn't that obvious?

Comment: @John3136: Perhaps this is quixotic, but for me the first step of debugging is to use a debugger. I really don't like "debugging" efforts that litter (and therefore potentially change the behaviour of the code) with `cout`.

Comment: @John3136 - To be fair, if `choice` is a newline, it isn't an obviously useful information

Comment: This did all start because I wanted to try using getChar() to get the choice.  I had it all working, but thought I'd try something different.

Comment: I'm too much of a noob to know how to use a debugger.

Comment: @Matt: If I were teaching C++ I would (1) start with Hello World, (2), teach debugging properly, (3) move on.  You must learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @John3136, printing choice would just get wiped once the default code ran, so it isn't much of a debugging step.

Comment: @Bathsheba - (4) profit? That's a course I'd actually recommend

Comment: @Matt Ok so remove the `clear()`. You either need to learn to use a debugger or learn simple debug steps like adding some prints to your code.

Comment: @John3136, even then, I wouldn't have seen the new line character in the output that's causing the problem.  Thanks for the constructive advice though.

Comment: @Matt the fact you didn't see what you expected should be enough to focus you to the area with the problem. You could try printing the choice as an int to see the char code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use [the standard `getchar` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar).

The problem is most likely that when you enter your "choice" you enter the `'p'` (for example) and then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. That <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will *also* be in the input as a newline `'\n'`. So the next time you call `getChoice` (and it calls `getchar`) you read that newline.

There are basically four ways to solve it:

1. The C way, using `scanf` instead of `getchar`, and ask `scanf` to read and discard leading whitespace (like newlines):

   ```
   char choice;
   scanf(" %c", &choice);
   // Note space in front of the %c, which tells scanf to discard leading whitespace
   ```
2. Read the character, and then read *and discard* everything else until the newline.
3. Read *the whole line* into a string, and the parse out the character.
4. Use `std::cin` and the normal formatted input operator `>>`, as that will skip leading whitespace.

I really recommend the last (number 4) method.

Comment: Some programmer dude, Thanks for the explanation!  I had it working with cin >> choice;  though then I had an array of strings and had to get the index to return to the switch statement.  I thought getchar() would make the whole thing simpler.  Oops!

Comment: @Matt Damn forgot about that `cin >>` thing... Added it to my list (with an explanation of why it works). Thanks for reminding me. :)

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks so much! I'll go take a look at scanf in the docs, I really appreciate it.

Comment: so when I first implemented the scanf(" %c", &choice); solution it did fix the multiple loop issue. That made me happy and I went to bed ;-) However, when getChoice() runs it always returns the 'start of heading' character (1). I still learned something new, so thank you! The other solutions have about the same level of complexity as my original solution, the one that worked, so i think I'm just going to leave it at that ;-)